# 500 Server error in BrilliantRetail when adding/editing products

Tags: brilliantretail

I have a new install of BrilliantRetail 1.8.0 on EE 2.10.1

When I try to add a new product, or edit any of the default products, I get a 500 server error.  I don't see anything relating to this in my server error log... (hosted on Nexcess)

I'm not having any issues anywhere else.  I have essentially the same configuration, version, addons etc on another site with zero issues.

What could possibly be causing this?

**UPDATE:**

EE error with debug on:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'bedellgu_weber_dev.exp_rte_toolsets' doesn't exist
>
> SELECT `exp_members`.`rte_toolset_id` FROM (`exp_members`) JOIN > `exp_rte_toolsets` ON `exp_members`.`rte_toolset_id` = > `exp_rte_toolsets`.`toolset_id` WHERE `exp_members`.`member_id` = 1
>
> Filename: modules/rte/models/rte_toolset_model.php
>
> Line Number: 101

Answer (score 1):

If its a 500 error there should be something in the log files.

Did you turn up all of EE's debugging options? https://gist.github.com/litzinger/5598641

Comment: Ah thank you, I've updated my post with the error that shows with debugging set to 2

Comment: That error message pretty much tells you what the problem is. EE is missing a table for whatever reason.

Comment: Yep, it was that I didn't have the Rich Text fieldtype installed and it is required with BR.  Thanks for the guidance!